# Avoiding inflated DF - spurious results computational modelling

Tags: statistical-significance, modeling, central-limit-theorem, degrees-of-freedom, spurious-correlation

I have a computer model comparing a number of paired groups of data
(reaction time & accuracy for 1 'subject' go together for a number of categories)
But since the program runs 500+ subjects for each category, differences can easily be spuriously large with DF so high.

How does one group or restructure this kind of information so it's truly "interesting" statistically?